# Bread like a brick name

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, food

What do you call bread that looks like a brick?

- A loaf of bread?
- A brick of bread?

[image]

Or some other way?

Comment: What do you mean, "what do you call"?   Are you looking for a noun? An adjective? Are you looking for a phrase that means "brick-shaped"?

Comment: So you all call it a loaf or loaves for plural? I'm looking for a noun.

Comment: I've never seen anything like that in a US supermarket, so I don't know that there is a term that would be widely understood in American English to mean this. *Brick* seems pretty descriptive, or maybe *slab*. What do you call it?

Comment: @1006a We call it a **буханка**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are

> loaves of bread

[image]
<sub>(source: [rackcdn.com](https://407e2ec7c6025ea4cb2a-d5c055bde1b705a7d77ea5f073cc868f.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/uploads/content/content_1372973606.jpg))</sub>

[image]

It is not easy to have a bread loaf form in the true shape of a brick since the top is not naturally flat.

In your example, bread in that form are **mini-loaves** since they are cut from a bigger production loaf

[image]

which is easily done with German pumpernickel which is notoriously dense and heavy.

Comment: +1....Thanks for the edit  -  I was just digging around for a picture of a mestemacher pumpernickel loaf to counter your original assertion.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll call these loaves.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a loaf of bread, or if you had the space, a loaf of bread that looked like a brick. Saying some bread is a brick in English implies it is "like a brick" in density.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with 'slab' as mentioned by @1006a

> **slab**
>
> a thick plate or slice (as of stone, wood, or **bread**):
>
> Examples of slab in a Sentence
>
> a thick slab of homemade bread
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slab

Answer (score 0):

If you zoom in on the image (and can read German) you will see that it does not show a solid mass of bread:

> Die Packung enthält 7 Scheiben zu je ca. 72 g.

So it is not a bread, or brick, or loaf, or slab at all. It is simply *7 slices of bread* packaged together.

Comment: And when soneone buys white sliced bread, isn't that a loaf too?

Answer (score 0):

To me (USA, first language) saying a brick of bread, while perhaps uncommon usage, would indiciate more specifically the rectangular prism shape that you see. If someone told me they had a brick of bread, I would also wonder as to whether or not the bread was stale or hard, like a brick.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a **loaf**, because it is not the entire unit that was baked in one go.

***Brick of bread*** is not an expression generally used in English, at least not in any dialect with which I am familiar.

This is a **pack** (or ***packet***, preference may depend on dialect) of bread containing 7 slices cut from a larger loaf.